# Jquery Ui Sortable bug with bootstrap grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

This pretty much has me beat.
Turning the placeholder option on in jquery ui causes it to only appear in the top left corner and if you look at the animation once an element has been sorted it goes up to the top left corner before going in the place it was dropped.

```
$(".widget-row").sortable({
        connectWith:".widget-row",
        helper:"clone",
        revert:true,
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        opacity:0.5,
         grid: [ 20, 10 ] ,
        start: function(e, ui ){
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight());
            ui.placeholder.width(ui.helper.outerWidth());
            //console.log(ui.helper.attr('id'));
        },
        update: function(event, ui){
            arrange_doc();
        }
    });
```

Sample is on [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47M3j/)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think its bcoz the sortable elements have different width.Is it really necessary to have diffrent width?

Comment: Yes, the items will become widgets and the user can select the width, it works perfectly fine except when i turn the placeholder option on @Arunu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a ton of research i have found it, giving the placeholder a bootstrap class such as span1-2-3-4... makes it behave normally again.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17502602/1401094) containing the solution.